# sympy poor matrix exponential (sympy.exp(...)) performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I am trying to calculate the matrix exponential of a 3x3 matrix. The matrix contains a single symbol.

```
import sympy as sym

_s_0 = sym.symbols('_s_0')

matrix = sym.Matrix([[-0.0113447284828316, 3.78157616094388e-5, -0.0227272727272727],
[ -0.831946755407654,   -1.66389351081531,                   0],
[              0.005,                   0,        -5.0e-8*_s_0]])

matrix_exponential = sym.exp(matrix)
```

(Sympy v1.9, Python v3.7)

I would consider this a small matrix that doesn't take much time to solve. But after 30 minutes sympy is still calculating. Does anyone know what is the reason for this? How could I improve the performance?

For performance improvement I have already looked into symengine. Unfortunately I did not find a function to calculate the matrix exponential.

Comment: If matrix exponentiation is the limit of `sum(M**k/k!, (k,0,oo))`, how will you know this has converged for an unknown value of `_s_0`?

Comment: I have assumed that sympy does not try to solve the problem this way, but for example by a Jordan-Chevalley decomposition followed by  Matrix diagonalization.
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Using_the_Jordan%E2%80%93Chevalley_decomposition)

Answer (score 0):

Note that although the matrix might look simple that does not mean that there is any simple expression for the matrix exponential. The eigenvalues here will be roots of a cubic and so Cardano's formulae will give complicated expressions for the eigenvalues and hence for the diagonalisation and in turn the matrix exponential. The fact that the cubic formula is much more complicated than the cubic polynomial it solves often leads to this kind of blowup that can surprise people.

The `exp` code is slow here because it is computing the Jordan normal form and the code for doing that is slow because it works with the complicated explicit formulae for the eigenvalues. The eigenvects routine was changed to use a much more efficient method than the Jordan normal form routine and could be used in this case since the matrix is diagonalisable. You can use that directly starting from `matrix.eigenvects` to build the matrix exponential. That will give extremely complicated formulae though because explicit formulae here require Cardano's formula for the cubic which is usually too complicated to be of much use.

Instead I suggest taking the method from this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21585

The code for completeness is

```
def expMt(M, t=1):
    """Compute matrix exponential exp(M*t)"""

    assert M.is_square
    N = M.shape[0]
    s = Dummy('s')

    Ms = (s*eye(N) - M)
    Mres = Ms.adjugate() / Ms.det()

    def expMij(i, j):
        """Partial fraction expansion then inverse Laplace transform"""
        Mresij_pfe = apart(Mres[i, j], s, full=True)
        return ilt(Mresij_pfe, s, t)

    return Matrix(N, N, expMij)


def ilt(e, s, t):
    """Fast inverse Laplace transform of rational function including RootSum"""
    a, b, n = symbols('a, b, n', cls=Wild, exclude=[s])

    def _ilt(e):
        if not e.has(s):
            return e
        elif e.is_Add:
            return _ilt_add(e)
        elif e.is_Mul:
            return _ilt_mul(e)
        elif e.is_Pow:
            return _ilt_pow(e)
        elif isinstance(e, RootSum):
            return _ilt_rootsum(e)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError

    def _ilt_add(e):
        return e.func(*map(_ilt, e.args))

    def _ilt_mul(e):
        coeff, expr = e.as_independent(s)
        if expr.is_Mul:
            raise NotImplementedError
        return coeff * _ilt(expr)

    def _ilt_pow(e):
        match = e.match((a*s + b)**n)
        if match is not None:
            nm, am, bm = match[n], match[a], match[b]
            if nm.is_Integer and nm < 0:
                if nm == 1:
                    return exp(-(bm/am)*t) / am
                else:
                    return t**(-nm-1)*exp(-(bm/am)*t)/(am**-nm*gamma(-nm))
        raise NotImplementedError

    def _ilt_rootsum(e):
        expr = e.fun.expr
        [variable] = e.fun.variables
        return RootSum(e.poly, Lambda(variable, together(_ilt(expr))))

    return _ilt(e)
```

With that you can compute the matrix exponential in terms of `RootSum` which is a special symbolic object that represents the sums of functions of the roots of a polynomial without needing an explicit representation for those roots:

```
In [38]: %time expM = expMt(nsimplify(matrix))
CPU times: user 986 ms, sys: 2 ms, total: 988 ms
Wall time: 987 ms
```

Even in this form the expressions are still complicated:

```
In [40]: len(str(expM))
Out[40]: 11764
```

I'll just show the top-left element:

```
In [41]: expM[0,0]
Out[41]: 
                     ⎛                                            3    2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ⎛                        2 ⎛                                                   3                                                              2                                                                                                                                           ⎞              ⎛                                                          4                                                                     3                                                                            2                                                                                                                                                                         ⎞                                                                     4                                                                            3                                                                                    2                                                                                                                                                                                    ⎞  a⎞
1100000000000⋅RootSum⎝275000000000000000000000000000000000000000⋅w  + w ⋅(13750000000000000000000000000000000⋅_s₀ + 460690515806988940000000000000000000000000) + w⋅(23034525790349447000000000000000000⋅_s₀ + 5230917221297823498336106489158180000000) + 259983361064891174916805324457909⋅_s₀ + 51996672212978437500000000000000000000, a ↦ ⎝6250000000000000000000⋅a ⋅⎝19527187759983387343750000000000000000000000000⋅_s₀  - 1304089038167929245399798822195451253125000000000000000⋅_s₀  + 21918487601058974721875885450998700790554909778693900000000000⋅_s₀ - 4855723672730472550971349847092177189986504137286997742620489912719⎠ + 20000000⋅a⋅⎝305112308749740427246093750000000000000000000000000000⋅_s₀  - 10223135754661341089143906478854804687500000000000000000000000⋅_s₀  - 335608725506451147679763265913525484737706213873652343750000000000000⋅_s₀  + 11322262734063555027299689886201756412827378961577104011736651815650000000000⋅_s₀ - 2555398954888472638194119398070651170586427042958572838132866827420717371808384811⎠ + 10153255466712553370227950117949121142578125000000000000000000⋅_s₀  - 678071225531690821326017335460380184590126679165744531250000000000000⋅_s₀  + 11396290497670079628252149456534515627612324338722213351465096970536234375000⋅_s₀  - 2478816750962556944737473521891532415426508480019357603757866827420717371808384811⋅_s₀ - 1018711046044901302852970029239460782969396294815174580192865630546875000000000000000000⎠⋅ℯ ⎠
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            4                                                                                        3                                                                                                2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              11092174275009282841443193132747781357421875000000000000000000000000000000⋅_s₀  - 743311891329062625314017356712668255282835495417202187500000000000000000000000000⋅_s₀  + 12618529991936109718156565931846031092273117033144567567486820898929431250000000000000000⋅_s₀  - 5487781359365218957636112086181060299390301614293415588335566497897297761612854879300000000000⋅_s₀ - 1599012654329320777936132388166625110553494385068047026787501508153708195520799867542679561459152629
```

You can substitute values for the symbol and evaluate numerically e.g.:

```
In [54]: expM.subs(_s_0, 0).evalf()
Out[54]: 
⎡0.988653376171146   1.82904746611005e-5  -0.0225983315683418⎤
⎢                                                            ⎥
⎢-0.402390442544212   0.189394508778724   0.00580287814851019⎥
⎢                                                            ⎥
⎣0.0049716329450352  5.80287814851018e-8   0.999943396717986 ⎦
```

If you call `expM.doit()` then the RootSums will be expanded using Cardano's formula but it's possibly not a good idea to do that. At this point the question is really what you actually want to do with this matrix exponential. The formulae are sufficiently complicated that it's hard to do much more than substitute values and evaluate numerically. It is potentially not useful to compute this symbolic representation if all you can do with it is evaluate numerically given that you could have computed this numerically in the first place.